# phpmyadmin on xampp is inaccessible

Tags: phpmyadmin

Since this morning ,after an update, I can't access my phpmyadmin.
I have this message:

```
phpMyAdmin - Error


Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!
```

please, How can I solve this ?

Comment: The config file is called `config.inc.php` and it is located in the root of the `phpmyadmin` folder. It is world writable, meaning, its permissions include a `w` in this place: `--------w-`. That is very undesirable because anyone can see and change the database password. Navigate to that directory and do `sudo chmod a-rw config.inc.php`.

Comment: I used `sudo chmod 775 -R /opt/lampp` But now I  have when trying to access phpmyadmin
`Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.`

Comment: Everything is right now.